# Custom webpart Personalization properties not saving in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part, personalization

I've inherited a VB.NET / MOSS 2007 Sharepoint application and have been tasked with adding a new custom Webpart.

I've declared a number of public properties to store configuration data for the webpart, like so:

```
Public Class CustomWebPart
    Inherits WebPart

    <Personalizable> _
    Public Property PrimaryID() As Int32

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        MyBase.CreateChildControls()

        Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(PrimaryID.ToString())
    End Sub

End Class
```

This webpart has been added to a Sharepoint page in the standard way, within a WebPartManager etc..

I've created a custom EditorPart, with which I am able to correctly Sync and Apply changes to these configuration values.  My custom EditorPart has the following ApplyChanges method:

```
Public Overrides Function ApplyChanges() As Boolean
    Dim part = DirectCast(Me.WebPartToEdit, CustomWebPart)
    part.PrimaryID = idSelector.SelectedValue

    part.SetPersonalizationDirty()
End Function
```

After editing and returning to the page, I see it showing the selected value for my property, and correctly rendering the report as specified in CreateChildControls() (simplified here).  However, as soon as I refresh the page, my personalized properties return to their default values.

Here's what I've looked into so far:

- My account has administrative permissions
- Webpart is configured for Shared-level personalization (as it should be)
- Personalization (digging into WebPartManager.Personalization) IsEnabled, IsModifiable, but ProviderName = "" and HasPersonalizationState is uninitialized.
- Other custom webparts, with seemingly identical code, store personalized properties just fine.

Anyways - I'm at a loss.  Thoughts?  Happy to provide more code as required.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is some mistake here: `<Personalizable> _
    Public Property PrimaryID() As Int32`, did you try changing to `<Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)> _`

Comment: Good call - tried and no dice.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Inadvertently figured this one out while working through an unrelated issue.

I had another property defined as

```
<Personalizable> Public Property IDs As IEnumerable(Of Int32)
```

later in the code.  Can't serialize an interface though, especially one that represents an in-memory query - so it was killing Personalization altogether on my page.  I replaced all my array-type properties with Lists, like so:

```
<Personalizable> Public Property IDs As List(Of Int32)
```

And now personalization is working.  Hooray!

Comment: Please mark this as answer if your problem is solved. Thanks!